# How to Animate a 3D Graph on Python

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

I'm looking to animate my graph (below) and I'm not sure if this is the correct code to animate 3 different plots on the same graph in 3D. I also am wondering if I have to animate all three plots separately or if I can do it under one function. If anyone can give me any suggestions on how to modify this code so that it can satisfy this issue, I would greatly appreciate it. If you need other portions of code to help me with this, comment down below and I'll post those portions as soon as possible.

```
def func(length, dims=2) :

    lineData = np.empty((dims, length))
    lineData[:,0],lineData[:,1],lineData[:,2] = x1,x2,x3
    for index in range(1, length) :

        step = ((x1 - 0.5) * 0.1)
        lineData[:, index] = lineData[:, index-1] + step

     return lineData

 def updatelines(num, dataLines, lines) :
     for line, data in zip(lines, dataLines) :

         line.set_data(data[0:2, :num])
         line.set_3d_properties(data[2,:num])
    return lines

 fig = plt.figure(figsize = (15,15))
 ax = fig.add_subplot(111,projection = '3d')

 data = [func(500, 500) for index in range(50)]

 lines = [ax.plot(x1[:,0], x1[:,1], x1[:,2])[0] for dat in data]


 ax.set_title('3 Body Problem')


 line_ani = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, updatelines, 25, fargs=(data, lines),
                          interval=100, blit=False)

 ax.plot(x1[:,0],x1[:,1],x1[:,2],color = 'b')
 ax.plot(x2[:,0],x2[:,1],x2[:,2],color = 'm')
 ax.plot(x3[:,0],x3[:,1],x3[:,2],color = 'g')

 ax.scatter(x1[-1,0],x1[-1,1],x1[-1,2],color = 'b', marker = 'o', s=30, label = 'Mass 1')
 ax.scatter(x2[-1,0],x2[-1,1],x2[-1,2],color = 'm', marker = 'o',s=90, label = 'Mass 2')
 ax.scatter(x3[-1,0],x3[-1,1],x3[-1,2],color = 'g', marker = 'o',s=60, label = 'Mass 3')
 ax.legend()
 plt.show()
```

ERROR MESSAGE:

```
 Traceback (most recent call last)
 <ipython-input-47-3faf8380342f> in <module>
      20 ax = plt.axes(projection = '3d')
      21 
 ---> 22 data = [func(500, 500) for index in range(50)]
      23 
      24 lines = [ax.plot(x1[:,0], x1[:,1], x1[:,2])[0] for dat in data]

 <ipython-input-47-3faf8380342f> in <listcomp>(.0)
      20 ax = plt.axes(projection = '3d')
      21 
 ---> 22 data = [func(500, 500) for index in range(50)]
      23 
      24 lines = [ax.plot(x1[:,0], x1[:,1], x1[:,2])[0] for dat in data]

 <ipython-input-47-3faf8380342f> in func(length, dims)
      2 
      3     lineData = np.empty((dims, length))
----> 4     lineData[:,0],lineData[:,1],lineData[:,2] = x1,x2,x3
      5     for index in range(1, length) :
      6 

ValueError: could not broadcast input array from shape (50,3) into shape (500)
```

[image]

Comment: you should update all the `Artists` (lines, scatters, etc...) in a single update function. I'm not sure I understand your problem. Does your code not work? In what way?

Comment: It doesn't work. If I run the code, an error pops up pointing to the data = [func(500,500) for index in range(50)] line saying that 'could not broadcast input array from shape (500,3) into shape (500)'.I'm not sure what this means or how to fix it. This is the first time I'm doing animations too

Comment: always put full error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not comment) as text (not screenshot). There are other useful information.

Comment: This error means you're trying to place data inside of your empty array but it wont fit because the shape isn't correct. You need to examine the contents of `x1`, `x2`, `x3` - they seem like external variables defined outside of the scope of `func`

Comment: When I print out x1, x2, and x3, they have a length 50, each index having an array with 3 numbers. I'm not sure how to modify the code to animate data like this.

Comment: Is there a pseudo-code or algorithm that you can offer, Because I'm not even sure that this is the right animation code to animate something of this complexity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably you started to work from the random walk code at [this example](https://matplotlib.org/gallery/animation/simple_3danim.html).
It's a nice example, but it's not always easy to understand what they are doing.

The example has a function `Gen_RandLine` which they call 50 times, once for each of their walks. You have only 3 walks, so you should only call it 3 times. Also, you already have the full trajectories in x1, x2, x3, while they generate the trajectories from scratch. Your situation differs, because your trajectories depend on each other, while in the example the trajectories are random and independent.

Anyway, I called that function `generate_lines_from_x123` to better convey what it does.

I also created some test-data for x1,x2,x3 as I don't have your simulation function. Just 3 spirals that are easy to program.

In the function `updatelines` `dataLines` contains all the data, while `lines` only contains the lines that are actually drawn during each step.

Here is the adaption of your code, which seems to function as intended:

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.animation as animation
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D

N = 500  # number of steps
x1 = np.zeros((N, 3))
x2 = np.zeros((N, 3))
x3 = np.zeros((N, 3))
t = np.linspace(0, 20, N)
x1[:,0] = np.sin(t)
x1[:,1] = np.cos(t)
x1[:,2] = t
x2[:,0] = np.sin(t+1)
x2[:,1] = np.cos(t+1)
x2[:,2] = t
x3[:,0] = np.sin(t+2)
x3[:,1] = np.cos(t+2)
x3[:,2] = t

def generate_lines_from_x123(length, x1, dims=3):
    lineData = np.empty((dims, length))
    lineData[:,0] = x1[0]
    for index in range(1, length) :
        lineData[:, index] = x1[index]
    return lineData

def updatelines(num, dataLines, lines) :
     for line, data in zip(lines, dataLines) :

         line.set_data(data[0:2, :num])
         line.set_3d_properties(data[2,:num])
     return lines

fig = plt.figure(figsize = (15,15))
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection = '3d')
ax.set_title('3 Body Problem')

do_animation = True
if do_animation:
    data = [generate_lines_from_x123(N, x, 3) for x in (x1, x2, x3)]
    lines = [ax.plot(x[:,0], x[:,1], x[:,2])[0] for x in (x1, x2, x3)]
    line_ani = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, updatelines, N, fargs=(data, lines),
                          interval=100, blit=False)
else:
    # just plot the 3 curves

    ax.plot(x1[:,0],x1[:,1],x1[:,2],color = 'b')
    ax.plot(x2[:,0],x2[:,1],x2[:,2],color = 'm')
    ax.plot(x3[:,0],x3[:,1],x3[:,2],color = 'g')

    ax.scatter(x1[-1,0],x1[-1,1],x1[-1,2],color = 'b', marker = 'o', s=30, label = 'Mass 1')
    ax.scatter(x2[-1,0],x2[-1,1],x2[-1,2],color = 'm', marker = 'o',s=90, label = 'Mass 2')
    ax.scatter(x3[-1,0],x3[-1,1],x3[-1,2],color = 'g', marker = 'o',s=60, label = 'Mass 3')
    ax.legend()

plt.show()
```